# When a video had stopped, other video stopped simultaneously in react native video

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-video

I have developed react-native cli, react-native-video (Currently, tried to expo-video).

In a screen, there are one flatList, it has a renderItem(column2). In a renderItem renders image or video thumbnail. Like shopping app UI AMAZON.

The problem is videos. It will stops automatically by user's swipe down to phone's view. Simultaneously, below stopped video, other video player will stops. This video is in exactly middle of user's phone view!

How can i solve this?

1. FlatList,

```js
const [videoPlayback, setVideoPlayback] = useState(false);
 const viewabilityConfig = {
    itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 80,
  };

  const _onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback((props) => {
    const changed = props.changed;
    changed.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.item.vimeoId) {
        if (item.isViewable) {
          setVideoPlayback((prev) => true);
        } else {
          setVideoPlayback((prev) => false);
        }
      }
    });
  }, []);
...
      <FlatList
        ref={ref}
        numColumns={2}
        data={posts}
        keyExtractor={(item: any) => `${item.postId}`}
        viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
        onViewableItemsChanged={_onViewableItemsChanged}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <PostContainer item={item} videoPlayback={videoPlayback} navigation={navigation} index={index} />
        )}
```

2. PostContainer

```js
const PostContainer = ({ item, videoPlayback }) => {
  const videoPlayer = useRef(null);

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      videoPlayer?.current?.seek(0);

      if (videoPlayer && !videoPlayback) {
        videoPlayer?.current?.seek(0);
      }
    }, [fadeAnim, videoPlayback]),
  );

  return (
    <View>

      { // This place that image component rendered}

      {item.vimeoId && (
        <StyledVideo
          ref={videoPlayer}
          paused={!videoPlayback}
          repeat={true}
          resizeMode={"cover"}
          volume={0}
          source={{
            uri: item.vimeoThumbnail,
          }}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: start by showing the code, not sure how you expect anyone can help you with the information you provided

Comment: Provide your code also , so we can identify the problem.

Comment: @Krismu  Very thank you! I had editted my article for your advice.

Comment: @GauravVanani Very thank you! I had editted my article for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. There are no fault in my logic. the important thing  is 'What videos are current playing?'

1. FlatList

```js
  const _onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback(
    (props) => {
      const changed = props.changed;
      changed.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.item.vimeoId) {
          const tempId = item.item.vimeoId;

          if (item.isViewable) {
            if (readVideosVar.list.indexOf(tempId) === -1) {
              dispatch(postSlice.actions.addId(tempId));
            }
          } else {
            dispatch(postSlice.actions.deleteId(tempId));
          }
        }
      });
    },
    [dispatch],
  );
```

2. redux

```js
    addId: (state, action) => {
      if (state.list.indexOf(action.payload) !== -1) {
        return;
      } else {
        let tempA = [];
        tempA.push(action.payload);
        state.list = state.list.concat(tempA);
      }
    },
    deleteId: (state, action) => {
      if (state.list.indexOf(action.payload) === -1) {
        return;
      } else {
        let stand = state.list;
        let findIdx = stand.indexOf(action.payload);
        let leftA = stand.slice(0, findIdx);
        let rightA = stand.slice(findIdx + 1);
        state.list = leftA.concat(rightA);
      }
    },
```

Compared to the existing code, I had added 'redux-toolkit'. In dispatch logic, "onViewalbeItems" had tracked chagend viewable items by real-time.

And then, I also added,

```js
export const viewabilityConfig = {
  minimumViewTime: 1000,
  viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 0,
};
```

This is just sugar.

I solved it like this !

Answer (score 0):

All the videos in your list share the same videoPlayback state. If you want each video to be controlled individually, move your videoPlayback state logic into your PostContainer.

Comment: I have tried to apply your answer in my code. But, I cannot solve problem. By writing   "const [playing, setPlaying] = React.useState(false);" at PostContainer.    "" if (videoPlayer && !videoPlayback) {  setPlaying((prev) => true); videoPlayer?.current?.seek(0);  } "". And StyledVideo component, I had changed "paused={!videoPlayback}" to  "paused={!playing}"

Comment: As I look at it, "if (videoPlayer && !videoPlayback)" this condition is fault. 
Do you have any opinions on this?